# Problems with Cosmic Cuttlefish and Gnome lockscreen (may be related to AMD gpu)

Tags: amdgpu

Ever since I upgraded to Cosmic Cuttlefish, one of my three computers (Ryzen 1700 CPU, Radeon RX 550 graphics card) is experiencing some very strange symptoms. Overall, it runs smoothly with the exception that when I'm using Gnome on Xorg, logging back in after suspend is *extremely* slow. The computer will quickly resume and show me the Gnome lockscreen. However, the lockscreen is unresponsive and will not allow me to login. The monitors then automatically power off. *If* I'm lucky, they will turn back on after a minute or two and I finally get to login. However, other times I have to force reboot the computer. When checking the system log, I found an error message related to `amdgpu` (pasted at bottom).

I tried the following:

- Disabling the lockscreen (i.e., no password to login). Same symptoms (except, when the screen finally comes back after a minute or two I don't have to type my password).
- Switching to Gnome on Wayland. Much faster time from resume to logging in. However, more frequent `amdgpu` errors (thereby requiring a restart).

What's the easiest way to fix this? I'm pretty frustrated because I chose AMD over Nvidia due to the fact AMD supports open-source. Yet, this seems to be related to AMD's drivers.

`Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: [drm:generic_reg_wait [amdgpu]] *ERROR* REG_WAIT timeout 10us * 3000 tries - dce110_stream_encoder_dp_blank line:927
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: WARNING: CPU: 15 PID: 3598 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dc_helper.c:254 generic_reg_wait+0xe4/0x160 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) ccm xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat_
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport sunrpc ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq libcrc32c algif_skcipher af_alg d
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: CPU: 15 PID: 3598 Comm: gnome-shell Tainted: G        W  OE     4.18.0-10-generic #11-Ubuntu
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME B450-PLUS, BIOS 0409 08/24/2018
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RIP: 0010:generic_reg_wait+0xe4/0x160 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: Code: a9 44 8b 45 20 48 8b 4d 18 89 de 44 89 4d d4 8b 55 10 48 c7 c7 d0 b3 b2 c0 e8 28 c7 a8 ff 41 83 7c 24 20 01 44 8b 4d d4 74 02 <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 18 44
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffbe084338f798 EFLAGS: 00010297
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 000000000000000a RCX: 0000000000000000
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffa0a21efd64b8 RDI: ffffa0a21efd64b8
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RBP: ffffbe084338f7d8 R08: 000000000005e2a3 R09: 0000000000010200
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: R10: 0000000000000004 R11: ffffffffab78480d R12: ffffa0a1fe838000
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: R13: 0000000000000bb9 R14: 0000000000010000 R15: 0000000000000000
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: FS:  00007fd746c48400(0000) GS:ffffa0a21efc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: CR2: 0000286ba76df9e0 CR3: 00000003d05a6000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: Call Trace:
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  dce110_stream_encoder_dp_blank+0x12f/0x1a0 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  dce110_blank_stream+0x57/0x90 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  core_link_disable_stream+0x57/0x220 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  dce110_reset_hw_ctx_wrap+0xcd/0x1e0 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? pp_dpm_dispatch_tasks+0x48/0x60 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  dce110_apply_ctx_to_hw+0x52/0xa30 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? amdgpu_pm_compute_clocks+0x17/0x20 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? pplib_apply_display_requirements+0x1c3/0x1d0 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? dce110_set_bandwidth+0x1d2/0x200 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  dc_commit_state+0x306/0x5b0 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? drm_calc_timestamping_constants+0x109/0x150 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0x37f/0xe40 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? wait_for_completion_timeout+0x38/0x140
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? wait_for_completion_interruptible+0x35/0x1a0
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  commit_tail+0x42/0x70 [drm_kms_helper]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  drm_atomic_helper_commit+0x113/0x120 [drm_kms_helper]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit+0x87/0xa0 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  drm_atomic_commit+0x4a/0x50 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  drm_atomic_connector_commit_dpms+0xe0/0x100 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  drm_mode_obj_set_property_ioctl+0x187/0x2b0 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? drm_mode_obj_find_prop_id+0x40/0x40 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xa4/0xf0 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x227/0x400 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ? drm_mode_obj_find_prop_id+0x40/0x40 [drm]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x4f/0x90 [amdgpu]
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x620
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  ksys_ioctl+0x67/0x90
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x110
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fd7518d23c7
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: Code: 00 00 90 48 8b 05 c9 3a 0d 00 64 c7 00 26 00 00 00 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffc4956e528 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005567d4e163e0 RCX: 00007fd7518d23c7
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RDX: 00007ffc4956e560 RSI: 00000000c01864ba RDI: 000000000000000b
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: RBP: 00007ffc4956e560 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 00005567d4e23930
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: R10: 00005567d4e12778 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000c01864ba
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: R13: 000000000000000b R14: 00007ffc4956e760 R15: 00007fd75268e8d0
Nov 07 19:50:48 phoenix kernel: ---[ end trace 0f20eacb3142b4af ]---`

Comment: Switched to KDE. While the problem still shows up in the logs, it no longer makes the computer unresponsive.